# Turn Dataframe into dictionary Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe

```
Index       Cat        Prod1      Prod2     Prod2
'Pens'   'Writing'     'Red'      'Blue'   'Green'
```

I was trying to use `to.dict()` to put into a dictionary in this format:

```
dic= {'Pens':['Writing',['Red','Blue','Green']]}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not a dictionary format. It has key: value pairs. Do you mean {'Pens':['Writing' :['Red','Blue','Green']]

Comment: @PandasJ It is a dictionary format (although it's missing the closing brace), the value is a list of lists.

Comment: Okay it requires meting, but I need to understand how he wants it

Comment: sorry yes I missed the } at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert first 2 columns to `MultiIndex` and then use `dict comprehension`:

```
a = df.set_index(['Index','Cat'])

d = {i: [j, list(v)] for (i, j), v in a.T.items()}
print (d)
{'Pens': ['Writing', ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

The first step is to "group" all *Prod...* columns into a list (in each row),
creating *Prod* column.

```
df['Prod'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(list, axis=1)
```

Then:

- set the index to *Index* column,
- take only *Cat* and *Prod* columns,
- again group them into a list,
- convert the above result to a dictionary.

The code to do it is:

```
df.set_index('Index')[['Cat', 'Prod']].apply(list, axis=1).to_dict()
```